# Ambiguous redirect, grep command

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

It was an exercise from one Linux textbook: to give an example both input and output redirected. I found an answer in web:

```
grep \$Id  <  *.c  > id_list
```

But this *.c seems to be the problem. Can this answer be worked around?

Comment: but then why `grep \$Id < 1.c 2.c` does not give an error? (it's just not working as expected). Is it because the redirect is interpreted before the `* `?  But I think this question would be better placed in unix.SE.

Comment: So, I would expect that $(1.c 2.c) will solve this..?

Comment: @RoVo please don't send questions like this away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to redirect more than of one file to input using `<`. ( or even output, for output you should use `tee`).

To demonstrate a working example, you can use something like: `grep \$Id < 1.c > id_list`.

You can also use "here string" type of redirection to get you want.

```
grep <<< $(cat *.c) > out
```

Comment: What does <<< mean?

Comment: `<<< $(cat *.c)` seems to put everything in one line. Use `< <(cat *.c)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since grep can read from files whose names are passed to it as arguments, you don't need input redirection at all here:

```
grep '$Id' -- *.c > id_list
```

By default, if `*.c` expands to a list of more than one file, then `grep` will prefix each match output with the filename in which it was found; if you don't want that, add the `-h` (or `--no-filename`) switch.

For a recursive search, you can make use of the `--include` option

```
grep -r --include='*.c' '$Id' . > id_list
```